# How to write onto virtual space in linux

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

How to write onto a virtual address space in `Kernel mode` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is a little confusing:
The virtual address space you want to access is kernel space or user space?

If it's kernel space, just go ahead to access it.

If it's user space. One point one should be clear is that on Linux, every process running has its own virtual space.

Which process'es virtual space you want to access in Kernel mode? If one don't know, it's meaningless to write onto it in Kernel mode.

Answer (score 0):

Tian has covered most points. One additional point on accessing process virtual address space.
If you do decide to access a process virtual address space, you will have to deal with the issue of the process virtual address being not valid OR being paged out. Please look into uiomove() for an example in accessing user space virtual addresses.